# Sublime Text - JSON formatter shortcut

Tags: json, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I'm using [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com).

How to reindent `Json` code with a **shortcut**?

I've already installed `packageControl` and it works.

I already tried `JsonReindent` package but it has not a shortcut by default and i don't know its command name.

I already have this command (from my previous sublimetext2 on another pc, where it works fine):

```
// JSON reindent
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+j", "ctrl+shift+j"], "command": "json_reindent" },
```

But here it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/ThomasKliszowski/json_reindent/blob/master/sublime_json_reindent.py#L13), the name of the [`sublime_plugin.TextCommand`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.TextCommand) subclass is `SublimeJsonReindentCommand`. Per the [conventions for command names](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html#conventions-for-command-names), the resulting command is named `sublime_json_reindent`. Simply change your key binding to:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+j", "ctrl+shift+j"], "command": "sublime_json_reindent" },
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: The command does nothing. In the console nothing appears.
If i put the command directly in the console:

`>>> sublime_json_reindent  
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
    NameError: name 'sublime_json_reindent' is not defined`

Comment: @user2342558 in the console, run `view.run_command("sublime_json_reindent")` and let me know what happens. Make sure you have a JSON file open and some text selected.

Comment: @user2342558 are you sure you have [JSON Reindent](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSON%20Reindent) installed?

Comment: I'm sure. It appear in the package control. I also already reinstalled it through package control.

Comment: Could be related with - https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/cant-open-user-keybinding-settings-for-packages/13152

Answer (score 278):

I have come across this issue too. I tried to figure it out by install jsFormat as follows:

1. Open Package Control panel <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (mac), install package.
2. Install [jsFormat](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat).
3. Edit the shortcut for the jsformat:
   [image: sublime text preferences, package settings, jsFormat]
4. Choose Key-Binding user, then edit

   ```
   [
     {
       "keys": [
         "command+l"
       ],
       "command": "reindent"
     },
     {
       "keys": [
         "ctrl+shift+s"
       ],
       "command": "auto_save"
     }, 
     {
       "keys": [
         "ctrl+alt+f"
       ],
       "command": "js_format"
     }
   ]
   ```
5. So next time when you try to format json code, just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for mac. Not mac,  just use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

That's all.

Comment: I would like to upvote this a couple more times. Thanks y0.

Comment: On Linux it's `CTRL + Shift +P` and if you haven't already you need to select `install package control` first before running `install package` and then searching for `jsformat`.

Comment: upvoted. Concise and helpful.FWIW on Mac this config is Ctrl-Option-F

Comment: ctrl + option + f in Mac

Comment: Use this for __control command j__: `"{ "keys": [ "ctrl+command+j" ], "command": "pretty_json" }"`

Comment: it is not available now

Comment: It was not working for me until i added "Key-binding user" configuration. After that works like a charm.

Comment: this is legit, works for MacOS 2022

Comment: This is a reference about how add User sublime3 setting.   https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/settings.html

Answer (score 167):

Install this packages via CMD + SHIFT + P > Install package > Search for Pretty JSON and install.

[image]

And then turn ugly json via CMD + CTRL + J (OSX) CTRL + ALT + J (Windows/Linux) in pretty JSON!

Source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson). 
[Credit](https://blog.adriaan.io/sublime-pretty-json.html)

Comment: This one was the answer for me!

Comment: Keep in mind you still need to set your key bindings for the shortcut as user Shubham Jain mentions below. CMD + CTRL + J does not work out of the box, at least for Sublime Text 3 and 4

Comment: Works excellent for me! thanks

Answer (score 139):

For sublime 4 below work for me on **MAC OS**  :

Install "Pretty JSON" sublime 4 by referring below:

- Use key combination **Cmd + Shift + p** and type **Install Package**
- Select **Package Control: Install Package** from the search results
- Type **Pretty JSON** and select it from the search results

OR use "Manual Installation" steps of below link

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON

---

now for shortcut :

Click on Sublime -> Preferences -> Key Bindings

Here add the below json part inside existing json and save the file

```
{ "keys": [ "ctrl+shift+j" ], "command": "pretty_json" }
```

you can use cmd too instead of ctrl, set says as per your preference

Complete json will look like below:

```
[{
    "keys": [
      "command+l"
    ],
    "command": "reindent"
  },
  {
    "keys": [
      "ctrl+shift+s"
    ],
    "command": "auto_save"
  },
  {
    "keys": [
      "ctrl+shift+k"
    ],
    "command": "js_format"
  },
  {
    "keys": [
      "ctrl+shift+j"
    ],
    "command": "pretty_json"
  }
]
```

---

Now use below short key anytime to beautify json on sublime

```
ctrl+shift+j
```

You can also use **command** instead of ctrl

[image]

Answer (score 38):

For Mac OS follow the steps:

**Install [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON)**

1. Use key combination `Cmd + Shift + p` and type `Install Package`
2. Select `Package Control: Install Package` from the search results
3. Type `Pretty JSON` and select it from the search results

**Add Key Binding**

1. Open key bindings from `Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings`
2. Add following key short cut in key bindings

   `{ "keys": [ "command+shift+j" ], "command": "pretty_json" }`

**Use [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON)**

1. Select JSON text and use key combination `Cmd + Shift + j`

Answer (score 14):

**Sublime Text with JSON formatter**

You can use `Command Palette` to format a text

1. Install [SublimePrettyJson](https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson)

2.1 Format using Command Palette

```
//Call Command Palette
Ctrl+Shift+P

//Format code instead of  CMD + CTRL + J (OSX)
pretty format
```

[image]

2.2 Format using custom shortcut

```
Sublime Text -> Settings... -> Key Bindings

//{ "keys": [ "<custom_shortcut >" ], "command": "pretty_json" }
{ "keys": [ "ctrl+i" ], "command": "pretty_json" }
```

[image]

Comment: As I know, you can bind to it a custom shortcut. See for example the accepted answer.

Comment: Thats not correct, you can bind it .. I hve mentioned same in my answer in this thread

Comment: This answer should be removed, because in my question I explicitly ask for a **shortcut**, not using the command palette...

Answer (score 5):

I am using Linux OS. I found the solution first installing the package controller then Pretty JSON package.

1. Install the package controller for sublime [here](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#Simple)
2. Install Pretty JSON packages via CMD + SHIFT + P > Install package > Search for Pretty JSON and install. Details are [here](https://blog.adriaan.io/sublime-pretty-json.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4 it is available under the Selection -> Format -> JSON menu option.

[image]

Comment: Is it a native feature or it still needs a package installed?

Comment: It comes with it now

Comment: it's not native, in Sublime 4216 there is no Format menu in Selection

Comment: In version 4126 there is.

Comment: Yes, there is it now.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Command Palette: Press Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows) or Cmd+Shift+P (OS X). Type 'install' in the Command Palette input box, which should autocomplete to 'Install Package Control'.
[image]

Then go to Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Package Control -> Type Package Control: Install Package in the pop up box which would open a separate pop up box and in that type the package you want to install in this case "Pretty JSON"

Turn ugly json to pretty JSON via CMD + CTRL + J (OS X)

Comment: Hi, what's the purpose of your answer? "Pretty JSON" is already suggested in other answers here.

Comment: I felt the some initial steps were missing and so I added this answer. I was struggling to install Pretty JSON since the answers did not explain how to install "Package Control" first. Only after installing Package Control you can install "Pretty JSON".